# I’m posting to a Firebase Database within React Native & Redux. Whenever I post anything, my fetch posts action doesn’t pull in the data again

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-redux, firebase-storage

Here is my `index.js` for my actions:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

export const config = {
  apiKey: '___APIKEY____',
  databaseURL: 'https://someurl.firebaseio.com',
  storageBucket: 'someurl.appspot.com'
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);
const posts = firebase.database().ref();
const storage = firebase.storage();

export const getRef = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    storage.refFromURL('gs://someurl.appspot.com/12345/Freemi1.jpg').getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
    console.log('URL', url
    )});
  };
};


export const fetchPosts = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    posts.on('value', snapshot => {
      dispatch({
        type: 'FETCH',
        payload: snapshot.val()
      });
    });
  };
};

export const addPost = (post) => {
  return dispatch => posts.push(post)
};
```

Here is the JSON data exported with the unique key post at the bottom that makes it fail:

```
{
  "0" : {
    "description" : "Need em out by tomorrow. Bring a truck.",
    "email" : "test@test.com",
    "id" : 0,
    "phone" : 1234567890,
    "picURL" : "https://s3-media4.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/KLgMdKOt3kEfRw_AQUmLjQ/348s.jpg",
    "title" : "Front Yard Boulders"
  },
  "1" : {
    "description" : "Got a bunch of moving boxes that are cluttering the garage! All holding up 
well.",
    "email" : "test@test.com",
    "id" : 1,
    "phone" : 1234567890,
    "picURL" : "https://i0.wp.com/spoonfulofimagination.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/moving-boxes.jpg?resize=350%2C200",
    "title" : "Moving Boxes"
  },
  "2" : {
    "description" : "Got some of leftover dirt from some backyard remodeling.",
    "email" : "test@test.com",
    "id" : 2,
    "phone" : 1234567890,
    "picURL" : "https://stuporglue.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/dirt_pile2-570x427.jpg",
    "title" : "Dirt"
  },
  "3" : {
    "description" : "A little cracked towards the bottom but holds well",
    "email" : "test@test.com",
    "id" : 3,
    "phone" : 1234567890,
    "picURL" : "https://www.tableandhearth.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/bookshelf-to-bar-cart-makeover-1.jpg",
    "title" : "Bookshelf"
  },
  "-Kw94Z2uIKkmWVr_8qRg" : {
    "title" : "Briefcase"
  }
}
```

Does anybody else have this problem? I have no rules in place for specifying a key needs to be a certain format. The posts pull in fine if it's the original 5, but if I add anything to the db it won't pull in anything anymore unless I delete the newest entry.

Comment: Hmmm, I did remember observer inside a dispatcher not working. What I did was moving the listener for post ref to a ghost component's component did mount method. I do agree that this is not a pretty way to do things, but I didn't find any other solution.

Comment: Do you call fetchPosts once before adding posts?

Comment: @AlexanderVitanov I have tried that, unfortunately it applies to any case. If I do the post in Postman, the data gets pulled from the app and doesn't rerender. If I do it manually inside of Firebase Database itself, same result.

Comment: @Jason can you elaborate more? I don't care about a janky way of doing it. I have to present this app to about 60+ people tomorrow and just want a working model lol

Comment: @Vinnii basically what I did was making a component that does not render anything, and put ref.on("value") function inside componentDidMount() of that component. Then put the component inside the top level index.js so that it will live through the entire lifecycle of the web app. Every time on("value") is triggered, you can save the data you get into a redux store. The point is componentDidMount() method is meant for async so it will always listen. Dispatcher, on the other hand, will be killed when you don't call it.